# Submit two POST requests from same URL with Ruby

Tags: ruby, post

I am trying to submit two POST requests from one page. The code below submits the first form, and leads to the next page at the same URL.

On the next page, I need to activate a download button to get a xlsx file back.

```
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('example.com/page1.asp')
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
req.set_form_data({"Firstname" => "name", "Lastname" => "lname", "submit1" => "Submit"})


puts res.body
```

This is the section that is returned from `puts res.body` I'm looking for:

```
<form  action="download.asp" method="post"  >
<input type="submit" value="Download"  name="Submit" />
<input type ="hidden" value="example.xlsx"  name="filename" />
</form>
```

Is there a way to trigger the Submit button, and then the Download button with ruby?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you saying you want to visit `example.com/page1.asp` programmatically, and on that page there is a form that you want to submit, and then after you submit that form you expect to be redirected to a different page, and on that different page there is another form that you want to submit, and after submitting you expect it to send you `example.xlsx`?

Comment: I visit the first page which has a form. Ive used my code above to submit the first form, which is a post request, so the URL does not change. On the new page, there is a link to download `example.xlsx` but that download performs a post request also. So I have to do a post request on a post request.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to read the values from the form and then submit them back:

```
uri = URI.parse('example.com/download.asp')
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true 
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
req.set_form_data({"Submit" => "Download", "filename" => "example.xlsx"})
```

Now, either the response is going to be the file data, in which case we do this:

```
File.open(“download/filepath.xslx”, ‘w’) do |f|
  f.write res.body
end
```

Or, it’s going to redirect you to a new URL and you’ll have to call a GET request once you arrive at the final file.